# vertical align and animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm working on a music library and i'm facing a problem with my vertical align and animation.

I have this html code :

```
<div id="player">
   <div class="player-disc"></div>
</div>
```

and this css for it:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#player {
  position:relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #E25822;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
 }

#player .player-disc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* animation: spin 5s infinite linear; */
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SFfrthBpqQA/maxresdefault.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

when i comment out the animation (as you can see above) the page looks just fine, but as soon as i'm adding the animation line, the 'disc' goes down out of position and start spinning, i can't seem to figure out what am i doing wrong.

here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozLnvdLu/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have this on your disc to move it within the player:

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

When you animate the rotate, via `transform`, the animation overwrites the translate.

You can solve this by adding the translate to the animate's transform too:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% { 
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that it's working? it doesn't fix the problem in this situation, the disc isn't spinning.

Comment: Try that now, I had the syntax and order of transforms wrong :)

Comment: Updated fiddle after some mobile browser wrangling! https://jsfiddle.net/x47oLx1h/